# Jquery.Ajax + IE9: Second request fails

Tags: caching, jquery, internet-explorer-9

I'm trying to get a file using an Ajax call in JQuery as follows:

```
$.ajax({
        cache: false,
        url: "../_filters.txt",
        success: function (data) {
            filters = data;
        }
```

Using IE9, the first request works and returns data. Using Fiddler, the timestamp was added to the request.

However, the second request does not work. Again, according to Fiddler, the request had a different timestamp and returned status code 200, yet no data was returned.

It is as if IE is still caching the file somewhere? I've searched around and it seems the using `cache: false` is supposed to fixe the IE Ajax cache issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, it turns out it was due to the file not being properly formatted so IE skipped over it.

Comment: Congrats on the solution! When you are able, please make sure to mark your answer as 'accepted' so that others might learn from your success. Cheers~

Answer (score 0):

Could you try adding dataType:

```
$.ajax({
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'text',  // or xml
        url: "../_filters.txt",
        success: function (data) {
            filters = data;
        }
//you could wrap your success code in if(xhr.status == 200) { .. to check whats getting in
```

Hope it works for you